# Catching Up Stellar Core Not Completed in a Long Time

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

I'm trying to run the stellar core and the horizon on my server using `stellar/quickstart` docker image. It's been a week since I started and it didn't synced. On the configuration file `stellar-core.cfg`, I put the line `CATCHUP_RECENT=5000000`, because I want to get the transaction history since last year. Using `http-command info` I found the status of stellar core is `Catching up to ledger 35137919: downloading ledger files 43720/48998 (89%)`. But my horizon is stuck with this ledger data.

```
  "ingest_latest_ledger": 0,
  "history_latest_ledger": 0,
  "history_latest_ledger_closed_at": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "history_elder_ledger": 0,
  "core_latest_ledger": 32002110
```

Can someone help me to understand how to read the stellar core status and how to estimate the time is needed until my stellar core synced? And why my horizon is stuck?